# How to display and update input values from the database on Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, database, eloquent

Am displaying user profile data from the database to an input field and at at the same time, the user should be able to update the input field

**Controller.php**

```
// shows details in input 
Public function details()
{
    $id = auth()->id;
    $details=Users::where(‘id’,’=‘,$id)->first();

return view (‘profile’,compact(‘details’);
}

// Update function 

Public function details()
{
    // I don’t know what to do
}
```

**blade.php**

```
<form action=‘{{ route(‘update’) }} method=‘post’>
@csrf
<input type=‘text’ name=‘firstname’ value=‘{{ $details->firstname}}’ >

<input type=‘text’ name=‘lastname’ value=‘{{ $details->lastname}}’ >

<input type=‘submit’ value=‘Submit’ >
</form>
```

Comment: Read up on some documentation https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#updates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

```
Public function details(Request $request, User $user)
{
 
    $user->firstname = $request->firstname;
    $user->lastname = $request->lastname;
    $user->save();
}
```

route:

```
Route::put('/user/{user}', ...);
```

blade:

```
<form action=‘{{ route(‘update’, $details->id) }} method=‘post’>
@csrf
{{method_field('PUT')}}
<input type=‘text’ name=‘firstname’ value=‘{{ $details->firstname}}’ >

<input type=‘text’ name=‘lastname’ value=‘{{ $details->lastname}}’ >

<input type=‘submit’ value=‘Submit’ >
</form>
```

Comment: {user} in route is the id of user, laravel will automatically bind the id to user model

Answer (score 0):

I hope you find this useful,

```
public function update(Request $request){

     $user= User::find($request->id);

     $user->firstname = $request->firstname;

     $user->lastname = $request->lastname;

     $user->save();
}
```

Change your **blade** file:

```
<form action="{{ route('user.update') }}" method="post">
```

Change your **web.php** file:

```
Route::post('user/update','UserController@update')->name('user.update');
```